# Android: is renaming the project's root folder recommended while renaming the app?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created an android app with the default root project folder named **MyApplication1**.

Now I wish to change the name of my app (which I can do without renaming my project folder, by just changing the app name in manifest file).
Will it effect me in any way if I do not change the project's root folder name?

Comment: what about checking yourself first?

Comment: You can rename the IDE project without affecting your own application name

Answer (score 0):

I did not face any problems when changing the projects folder name so I think you won't have any problems either. Although I would suggest you to also refactor the last part of your package name that should be your app name just to keep the 'standards'

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to rename the folder name as well. Because it can cause problems for you when you are trying to access your classes with full static package name in your activities or layout files. Sometimes we do that to pass intents o to create custom views in Layout files. In those kind of situations you will seriously have issues. So it's better to change it now.